# How can I add those values into the useState objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

In the _app.js file I used `AppContext.Provider` and I added the `card` and `setcard` to it:

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [count, setcount] = useState(0);
  const [card, setcard] = useState({
    pic: "",
    des: "",
    price: "",
    scroe: "",
  });

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        count,
        setcount,
        card,
        setcard,
      }}
    >
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I'm using `useContext` and `map` in the Mycards.js component:

```
const context = useContext(AppContext);

{Myjson.slice(firstpostindex, lastPostIndex).map((item) => {
  return (
    <Grid item key={item.itemId}>
       I removed the content here
    </Grid>
```

And inside the `Grid` I'm using the following code to add the value of `item.itemMainPic` to `pic` and it is working:

```
  <Button
    value={item.itemMainPic}
    sx={{ width: 308 }}
    variant="contained"
    endIcon={<AddShoppingCartIcon />}
    onClick={(e) => {
      context.setcount(context.count + 1);
      context.setcard({ pic: e.target.value });
    }}
  >
    add to card
  </Button>
```

I need to add the values of `item.itemMainPic` `item.itemName` `item.rangePriceFormat` `item.score` inside `pic` `des` `price` `score` I thought that I could easily use something like this:

```
context.setcard({ pic: e.target.item.itemMainPic});
context.setcard({ des: e.target.item.itemName});
context.setcard({ price: e.target.item.rangePriceFormat});
context.setcard({ score: e.target.item.score});
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'itemMainPic')

How can I add those values into the useState objects?

And when I'm clicking on the button multiple times, using `console.log(context.card);` I can see these:

```
{ "pic": "https://valid URL1.jpg" }
{ "pic": "https://valid URL2.jpg" }
{ "pic": "https://valid URL3.jpg" }
```

But what should I do to store them like this:

```
[
    { "pic": "https://valid URL1.jpg" },
    { "pic": "https://valid URL2.jpg" },
    { "pic": "https://valid URL3.jpg" }
]
```

I want `console.log(context.card);` look like this:

```
[
    { "pic": "https://valid URL1.jpg","des": "something", "score": "something", "price": "something"},
    { "pic": "https://valid URL2.jpg","des": "something", "score": "something", "price": "something"},
    { "pic": "https://valid URL3.jpg","des": "something", "score": "something", "price": "something"}

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your card useState should be an array since you want output to be an array of object, so change your card useState to be something like this below;

```
const [card, setCard] = useState([])
```

then to add new card object into the card array you can have a function that takes in the item/card you want to add, lets call the function addToCard;

```
const addToCard = (item) => {
  const newCard = {
    pic : item.itemMainPic,
    des : item. itemName,
    price : item. rangePriceFormat,
    score : item. score,
 }

 context.setcount(context.count + 1);
 
 context.setcard(prev => [...prev, newCard]);

}
```

Then in your button you can the `addToCard` function like this

```
     <Button
      sx={{ width: 308 }}
      variant="contained"
      endIcon={<AddShoppingCartIcon />}
      onClick={() => addToCard(item)}
     >
       add to card
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your 1 line of context.setcard on button click. Please try below code.

```
context.setcard(...context.card, { pic: item.itemMainPic, des: item.itemName, price: item.rangePriceFormat, score: item.score});
```

You don't have to write context.setcard for each key. Let me know if it works for you.